# PHP insert element between elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays, json, onesignal

I have PHP code that spits out a dynamic JSON array like this:

```
{"key":"user_email","relation":"=","value":"email@gmail.com"},
{"key":"user_email","relation":"=","value":"email@gmail.com"},
{"key":"user_email","relation":"=","value":"email@gmail.com"}
```

I need to adjust it to insert an element between each element like so:

```
{"key":"user_email","relation":"=","value":"email@gmail.com"},
{"operator":"OR"},
{"key":"user_email","relation":"=","value":"email@gmail.com"},
{"operator":"OR"},
{"key":"user_email","relation":"=","value":"email@gmail.com"}
```

This is my current PHP code that generates the JSON:

```
$jsonData = array();

$allStaffInit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

while ($staffrow = mysql_fetch_object($allStaffInit)){

    $object = new stdClass();
    $object->key = "user_email";
    $object->relation = "=";
    $object->value = $staffrow->value;

    $jsonData[] = $object;       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the separator object before your while loop.

```
$or = (object) ['operator' => 'OR'];
```

Then add it to the array in your loop after you add `$object`.

```
while ($staffrow = mysql_fetch_object($allStaffInit)){
    $object = new stdClass();
    $object->key = "user_email";
    $object->relation = "=";
    $object->value = $staffrow->value;
    $jsonData[] = $object;
    $jsonData[] = $or;      // << here
}
```

Before you `json_encode`, pop off the extra one after the last item.

```
array_pop($jsonData);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!